getRange return the word "info" instead of real value
I have a spreadsheet which values comes from an importRange built-in function, the thing is that the getRange function  is not fetching the right values, regardless the ROW, COLUMN selected,  it returns the word "info" all the time except for Row Column 1,1 (or A1), it returns #Error.
it is weird right? I dunno what am I doing wrong, hope you can help, it is driving me crazy,   here is my test function
function TestFunction()
{
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("OTs");
   Logger.log(ss.getRange(14,5).getValue().toString());
 }

and in the image is the data in that spreadsheet,

here is the results in the console:


Info is not the output. It is the label on the log. You are actually returning a blank output because there is a chance that E14 is blank.

It's not weird.
The image shows the code editor with the Execution Log panel. This panel includes three columns

Timestamp.
Log type.
Message.

The image shows three entries, two with Notice and one with Info. The Notice entries are added automatically by Google Apps Script to let you know when the execution started and ended. The Info entry corresponds to the Logger.log statement. This entry is logging an empty string.
Unfortunately, the spreadsheet image doesn't include the source cell, row 14, column 5, aka E14. This cell is likely blank.
